# A space between inline-block list items

Tags: html, css, xhtml

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Unwanted margin in inline-block list items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4969082/unwanted-margin-in-inline-block-list-items)
> [How to remove “Invisible space” from HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12183341/how-to-remove-invisible-space-from-html)

Why do the `inline-block` list items have a space in them? No matter how I make my list items into a menu, I always get spaces.

```css
li {
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 25px;
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: center;
  width: 50px;
}

ul {
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <li>Three</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: When you say space "in them" what does that mean. The space char is between the <li></li> tags? FYI: The html you have here is not valid. You don't have a <ul></ul> or <ol></ol>.

Comment: where does it have a space? Add a screenshot or a demo please

Comment: Do you mean horizontal space between each element. If you do then you can reset the margin and padding to 0 in your menu#headerMenu li definition and also remove the width 100px;

Comment: Yes, the space character is between the <li> tags. About the <ul> and <ol> thing, thanks. I forgot the the <menu> tag has been deprecated. Anyway, the spaces still applies to the <li> tag.

Comment: I updated the code to get rid of all the unnecessary code to help you see what's going on.

Comment: Found a solution here, explaining in a good way how to remove it.. http://www.ultimatewebtips.com/remove-space-between-li-with-display-inline-block/

Answer (score 256, accepted):

I have seen this and answered on it before:

After [further research](http://robertnyman.com/2010/02/24/css-display-inline-block-why-it-rocks-and-why-it-sucks/) I have
 discovered that `inline-block` is a
 whitespace dependent method and
 is dependent on the font setting. In this case 4px is rendered.

To avoid this you could run all your
 `li`s together in one line, or block
 the end tags and begin tags together
 like this:

> ```
> <ul>
>         <li>
>             <div>first</div>
>         </li><li>
>             <div>first</div>
>         </li><li>
>             <div>first</div>
>         </li><li>
>             <div>first</div>
>         </li>
> </ul>
> ```

[Example here](http://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_Sevenoaks/t7dut/).

---

As mentioned by other answers and comments, the best practice for solving this is to add `font-size: 0;` to the parent element:

```
ul {
    font-size: 0;
}

ul li {
    font-size: 14px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

This is better for HTML readability (avoiding running the tags together etc). The spacing effect is because of the font's spacing setting, so you must reset it for the inlined elements and set it again for the content within.

Comment: Actually it's due to word spacing, hence the 4px is dependent on the font setting. See http://jsfiddle.net/Cerebrl/Wt4hP/

Comment: Kyle, could you please update your answer so that you aren't giving people incorrect information? A 4px margin is not added to inline-block elements. As Anzeo mentions, it is due to a space being rendered between elements. The word 'margin' has specific meaning in CSS and it can mislead others into not understanding the nature of the problem.

Comment: I know it has been two years but this is way better http://jsfiddle.net/t7dut/647/ Maybe rendering engines are different now.

Comment: If you don't want to do this, I've found that leaving off the ending tags for `<li>` elements fixes the issue too. It's still considered well-formed HTML.

Comment: is this the best semantic result though, running the LI tags together?

Comment: Is there a better way to do this with CSS?

Comment: An interesting article about the space between Inline Block Elements may be found [here](https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/)

Answer (score 170):

Solution:

```css
ul {
    font-size: 0;
}

ul li {
    font-size: 14px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

You must set parent font size to 0

Comment: Huh. I never thought about that. Makes sense. The only reason I don't upvote this answer is that I can't use percentages or ems as my UOM for font-sizes inside a list. I could solve that problem with JavaScript but that's not ideal.

Comment: Great solution, worked with my complicated 2 level horizontal popup menu.

Comment: Down size to this method is you can't use em or %

Comment: This trick doesn't work for Safari

Comment: thanks, the font-size:0; solved the extra space issue for me

Comment: Confirmed that this does not work for Safari. Setting a font-size of 1px was the best workaround in my case. It still leaves an extra 1px space between elements on Safari, but in my case this negligible difference did not matter on the design.

Comment: This is a much more elegant solution than having all `<li>`s in a single line/remove the white space, since one may not necessarily have access to the markup every time.

Comment: Note that there are browsers (actually only Opera that I know of, but still...) that don't make the font-size 0 if the user has set a minimum font size in the preferences. Then font-size:0 will have the same effect as font-size:9px.

Comment: Works in safari (OSX - Versión 7.0.1).

Answer (score 18):

I would add the CSS property of float left as seen below. That gets rid of the extra space.

```css
ul li {
    float:left;
}
```

Comment: I know I'm late to the party but this solution, although it does remove the spacing between the `<li>`s, it introduces another potential problem: You wouldn't be able center and right align the list items. If you try to do `float:right;` on the `<li>`s then their order will be swapped, meaning: the first item in the list would be last, the second item is the one before the last, and so on.

Answer (score 18):

Actually, this is not specific to `display:inline-block`, but also applies to `display:inline`. Thus, in addition to David Horák's solution, this also works:

```css
ul {
    font-size: 0;
}
ul li {
    font-size: 14px;
    display: inline;
}
```

Comment: But you can't use relative font sizes with this solution. But yes, I have thought about this myself. :)

Comment: You can always use `rem`s, and provide fallbacks in pixels for legacy browsers. I did it and it works like a charm.

Answer (score 6):

Another solution, similar to [Gerbus' solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11906591/1366033), but this also works with relative font sizing.

```css
ul {
    letter-spacing: -1em; /* Effectively collapses white-space */
}
ul li {
    display: inline;
    letter-spacing: normal; /* Reset letter-spacing to normal value */
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this solution. Setting font-size to zero, even if just for the UL, caused problems with my layout since I use em-sizing in some places.

Comment: This is my new favourite solution to this problem, as my layout also uses em for sizing. It is working flawlessly for me.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, when I used a  inline-block on my menu I had the space between each "li" I found a simple solution, I don't remember where I found it, anyway here is what I did.

```
<li><a href="index.html" title="home" class="active">Home</a></li><!---->
<li><a href="news.html" title="news">News</a></li><!---->
<li><a href="about.html" title="about">About Us</a></li><!---->
<li><a href="contact.html" title="contact">Contact Us</a></li>
```

You add a comment sign between  each end of, and start of : "li" 
Then the horizontal space disappear.
Hope that answer to the question 
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Even if its not `inline-block` based, this solution might worth consideration (allows nearly same formatting control from upper levels).

```
ul {
  display: table;
}
ul li {
  display: table-cell;
}
```

- [IE8+ & major browsers compatible](http://caniuse.com/css-table)
- Relative/fixed font-size independent
- HTML code formatting independent (no need to glue `</li><li>`)

Answer (score 0):

just remove the breaks between li's in your html code...
make the li's in one line only..

Comment: I'm not one of the downvoters, but not to be rude, this questions has already been answered.

Comment: OMG. How many weeks have I been beating my head against the wall about the line break between the LI symbol and the text that follows. BTWs, this line break happened only with ridiculously large zooming. YOU ARE MY HERO!