# How to remove the space between list items

Tags: html, css

How to you get rid of the white space between list items? I am trying to make it so that the images are right next to each other. Even though I have set the styling to `margins: 0;`, they are still separated.

CSS

```
ul.frames{
  margin: 20px;
  width: 410px;
  height: 320px;
  background-color: grey;
  float: left;
  list-style-type: none;
}

ul.frames  li {
  display:inline;
  margin: 0;
  display: inline;
  list-style: none;
}

ul.frames li img {
  margin: 0 0 0 0;
}
```

HTML

```
<li>
  <img id="myImg" src="img.jpg" width="102.5px" height="80px"/>
</li>
<li>
  <img id="myImg2" src="img.jpg" width="102.5px" height="80px"/>
</li>
<li>
  <img id="myImg3" src="img.jpg" width="102.5px" height="80px"/>
</li>
<li>
  <img id="myImg4" src="img.jpg" width="102.5px" height="80px"/>
</li>
```

Comment: Show us the rest of the HTML, because you need the `<ul class="frames">` container for the CSS to work.

Comment: yes I have that, but the answer below worked

Comment: This is not a duplicate. Two questions can have the same answer yet still be different questions.

Answer (score 114, accepted):

**Updated Sept. 1st, 2014**

In modern browsers, [flex-box](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox) is the preferred method of doing this. It's as simple as:

```
ul {
  display: flex;
}
```

**[See a JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/jmeas/eoqqvwnr/)**.

For legacy browser support refer to the other options below, which are still just fine, albeit slightly more complex.

---

Though each of the other answers gives at least one good solution, none seem to provide *all* of the possibilities. And that's what I'll try to do here.

Firstly, to answer your implicit question of *why* there's spacing, it's there because you've set your LIs to display as inline elements.

`inline` is the default display value for text and images in all of the browsers that I know of. Inline elements are rendered with spacing between them whenever there's whitespace in your code. This is a good thing when it comes to text: these words that I've typed are spaced apart because of the space I've included in the code. And there's also space between each line. It's this very behavior of inline elements is what makes text on the web readable at all.

But sometimes we want non-text elements to be `inline` to take advantage of *other* properties of this display style. And this typically includes a desire for our elements to fit snugly together, quite unlike text. And that seems to be your problem here.

Without further ado, here are all the ways I know of to get rid of the spacing:

### Keeping them inline

1. (*Not recommended*) Apply negative margin to the LIs to move them over.

   ```
   li { margin: -4px; }
   ```

Note that you'll need to 'guess' the size of a space. This isn't recommended because, as Arthur excellently points out in the comments below, users can change the Zoom of their browser, which would more than likely mess up the rendering of your code. Further, this code requires too much guesswork and calculation. There are better solutions that work under all conditions.

2. Get rid of the whitespace

   ```
   <li>One</li><li>Two</li>
   ```
3. Use comments to make the whitespace a comment [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TG2TB/)

   ```
   <li>One</li><!--
   --><li>Two</li>
   ```
4. Skip the closing tag ([HTML4 valid](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/index/elements.html) / [HTML5 Valid](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#optional-tags)) [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yUFve/)

   ```
   <li>One
   <li>Two
   ```
5. Put the whitespace in the tag itself (*Note: Early Internet Explorers will not like this*)

   ```
   <li>One</li
   ><li>Two</li
   >
   ```
6. Take advantage of the fact that the spacing between the elements is calculated as a percentage of the font size of the parent. Consequently, setting the parent's font size to 0 results in no space. Just remember to set a non-zero font-size on the `li` so that the text itself has a nonzero font size. [View on JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/PLQE9/)

### Floating them

1. Float them instead. You'll probably want to [clearfix the parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8554043/what-is-clearfix) if you do this.

   ```
   li { float: left; display: block; }
   ```

Comment: I don't care if no.4 is valid ... it still looks completely wrong to me!

Comment: +1 and I don't think the negative margin is a good idea because you don't know the real size of the space character which could change with the zoom level of the browser.

Comment: That worked, but when I resize the images then there is a space between the two picture lines here is a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/jspence29/PP94M/

Comment: user, a few problems: (1) Close your UL. (2) Images are inline, so you need to set them to display: block; to get rid of their spacing (3) You overwrote your display:block; a few lines down in your LI properties. [View on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wV7TD/)

Comment: Thank you the images was the problem

Comment: +1. there's also the font-size:0; on the parent element way

Comment: font-size: 0 i think is best way for this, if you can't change markup.(even spaces)

Comment: ha @ПавелИванов did you downvote me because of that? I have that as the 5th item on this list, and I attempted to avoid saying that any given method is better than any other (other than flexbox, which is, assuming browser support, likely actually the best way to do this).

Comment: +1 didn't even think to use float...

Comment: After 2 years.. I love the `ul { font-size: 0; } ul li { font-size: $size; }` option the best. So I can still have my guidelines without "hacks".

Comment: Thank you guy for the answer

Comment: font-size: 0 in parent should be addded to the answer if possible as it suggests all methods. i am suprised i did know all =)

Comment: @sewo it's already there. Item 5 under "Keeping them inline"

Comment: If you float the li items left, then ```vertical-align: middle``` stops working.

Comment: Thanks for this answer! One addition -- you can use `ul { display: inline-flex; }` for inline lists.

Answer (score 32):

Incredible but no one here has provided the proper solution for this problem.

Just do this:

```
ul.frames {
  font-size: 0;
}
ul.frames li {
  font-size: 14px; font-size:1.4rem;
  display: inline;
}
```

Keep in mind that we won't always have access to modify the markup. And trying to remove the spaces from the `<li>`s with JavaScript would be totally unnecessary when the solution is simply two `font-size` properties.

Also, floating the `<li>`s introduces another potential problem: You wouldn't be able center and right align the list items.

If you try to do `float:right;` on the `<li>`s then their order will be swapped, meaning: the first item in the list would be last, the second item is the one before the last, and so on.

Check out this other post here in SO: [A Space between Inline-Block List Items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5256533/a-space-between-inline-block-list-items)

Comment: Perfect solution for those who need inline elements!

Comment: you're awesome bro, your answer is damn correct.

Answer (score 3):

You should just remove all the spaces in the ul tags just like this: http://jsfiddle.net/dFRYL/3/

Since the `<li>` elements are inline, in you write spaces in or between them you will have spaces displayed.

Answer (score 3):

The reason you get the spaces is because you have spaces between the elements (line break)

```
<ul>
     <li>One</li><li>
     Two</li><li>
     Three</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Mine was style sheet linking problems. If you are using bootstrap, styles from them can get inherited on to your elements. I've answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38962503/override-bootstrap-style-not-working/49657636#49657636

Answer (score 2):

You can use negative margins like this:

```
margin-right: -4px;
margin-bottom: -4px;
```

Take a look [here](http://jsfiddle.net/dFRYL/4/).

It also works up and down, I added another one to show that [here](http://jsfiddle.net/dFRYL/5/).

Comment: I can't see the jsfiddle

Comment: How about [this](http://jsfiddle.net/dFRYL/5/show/)?

Comment: @yentup can you undelete [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14175350/answer/submit) this question so i can answer or come to php chat room http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11/php or if you want to see the answer check this message in php chat room http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/7030329#7030329

Comment: This is not working if i using for example body { font-size: 90px; }

Answer (score 0):

Using `display:inline;` causes whitespace in your HTML to create whitespace when displaying the HTML.

There are two solutions to this:

1) Change how you make them appear inline, I would recommend using floats on all of the list items, then using a clearfix of sorts.

2) Remove all whitespace between your list items, e.g.

```
<li><img id="myImg" src="http://stephboreldesign.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/lorem-ipsum-logo.jpg" width="102.5px" height="80px"/></li><li><img id="myImg2" src="http://stephboreldesign.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/lorem-ipsum-logo.jpg" width="102.5px" height="80px"/></li><li><img id="myImg3" src="http://stephboreldesign.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/lorem-ipsum-logo.jpg" width="102.5px" height="80px"/></li><li><img id="myImg4" src="http://stephboreldesign.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/lorem-ipsum-logo.jpg" width="102.5px" height="80px"/></li>
```

Personally I would recommend option 1 (I hate `display: inline`)

Answer (score 0):

here is my attempt at it. Hope it helps. As Sean Dunwoody mentioned, white space in your html can be a cause of the space, but I've floated the li and made the image to display:block;. Left comment on where I made changes. Hope it helps: http://jsfiddle.net/FJ3nV/

Here my small but main changes:

```
/*
* Added float left
*/
ul.frames  li {
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none; 
  float:left;
}

/* 
*  Moved inline sizing here just to clear up obtrusive html.
*  Added display block.
*/
ul.frames li img{width:102px; height:80px; display:block;}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would change your li elements to inline-block.

One person did not recommend

```
li { margin: -4px; }
```

But making a slight change to it will cause it to work even when the font size changes or when the browser zooms in

```
li{ margin-right: -0.25em; }
```

That should fix that white space problem completely. However, if you are using a poorly designed font-face that doesn't follow correct letter-height standards then it may cause a problem. However those are harder to find and most of the fonts google hosts don't have that issue.