# Override bootstrap style not working

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, overwrite

I have this simple situation, I have an style with no defined **display** property value, I recently added bootstrap to my project with no major problems, just one.

In **label** bootstrap style is defined a **display: inline-block;** what I don't need and is causing some troubleshooting on my page. So simply I overwrite it, but it seems It's getting the bootstrap value. ***!important*** is not working also. As you can see in the image below:
[image]

Even, It's marked as overwritten on Developer Tools. I also tested removing the line from the bootstrap file and it works, but that's not viable option in my situation.
I'm stuck here, as I said, no more problems with bootstrap, and haven't had this situation before.

I have to add that I'm setting right position for style sheets on my page.

**EDIT:**

I'll attach the result and the expected result, when I remove the bootstrap style. It seems to be working even It is overwritten.

Expected result when bootstrap style is removed (this apply to in time Developer tools and when removing from bootstrap.css)[image]

PS: IE as needed browser.

**EDIT2:**

Problem solved, It was related to IE version, our company gives support to IE only on this application, and the problem was that some previous change was forcing IE to run compatibility on version 5, for reason that anyone knows, switched to IE as standards and it's working.

Thank you all any idea or comment.

Comment: do you import bootstrap.css before or after your own css ?

Comment: @singebatteur before, my css is the last import in page.

Comment: You have to call your style.css after your bootstrap.css, or it will not override anything

Comment: @singebatteur It its after bootstrap I mean, It's weird, because I'm overriding several styles and having trouble with this one only, and... object hasn't other selector, only It's ID and label html tag.

Comment: Have you tried on modern browsers ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was related as IE compatibility mode.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:
My problem was the way I linked it.

example: lets say `input` tag inherited style from vendors file(say bootstrap), and say you are too far in the project and linking files the other way round screws up your layout then, create a new style sheet and link it after the bootstrap link.

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="styleSheet.css">` 
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrapStyles.css">` 
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="newStyleSheet.css">`//*write the style for elements that you don't want styles from bootstrap to be inherited  and link it this way.*

right way of doing:
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrapStyles.css">` 
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="styleSheet.css">`