# Why does this CSS not fit?

Tags: css, positioning

I have a div with a width of 970px.  (That is, of course, excluding borders, margins and padding).  I am placing two divs inside this, side-by-side.  Here's their CSS:

```
#content { display: inline-block; width: 720px; border: 0px; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; }
#sidebar { display: inline-block; width: 246px; border: 0px; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; }
```

Now, this works fine when the total width of the internal divs is 966px or less. When I get larger than that, however, the second div sits beneath the first.  Why is this so?

As far as I know, I should be able to have a total width of 970px before I hit problems?

Comment: This is happening because of [`display: inline-block`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5256533/1577396).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I bet you have new line between these two `div`s in HTML, and that's the reason.

For following CSS:

```
#main { width: 970px; }

#content { display: inline-block; width: 720px; border: 0px; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; height: 200px; background: red; }
#sidebar { display: inline-block; width: 246px; border: 0px; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; height: 200px; background: blue; }
```

There is a difference between following 2 HTML markups:

```
<div id="main">
    <div id="content"></div><div id="sidebar"></div>
</div>
```

and

```
<div id="main">
    <div id="content"></div>
    <div id="sidebar"></div>
</div>
```

Check this example: http://jsfiddle.net/vnguQ/ and notice white line between elements in second part.

Comment: It is happening because of `display: inline-block`. replace it with `float: left` and check.

Answer (score 0):

There may be whitespace between both divs and `inline block` apply styles for that whitespace.Take a look at these links 
http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/
[display: inline-block extra margin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1833734/display-inline-block-extra-margin)
[How to remove the space between inline-block elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078239/how-to-remove-the-space-between-inline-block-elements)

Answer (score 0):

This problem happens when the main div having display property "block"(default one).

Add a property for the main div as `dispaly:inline`, it will automatically adjust the width for the inner divs. Change the css for main div.

```
#main { width: 970px; display:inline; }

#content { display: inline-block; width: 720px; border: 0px; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; height: 200px; background: red; }
#sidebar { display: inline-block; width: 246px; border: 0px; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; height: 200px; background: blue; }
```