# Spacing between 2 spans does not comply

Tags: html, css

I have this code:

```
<div class="mainmenu">
    <span class="mainmenuitem">
        Item1
    </span>
    <span class="mainmenuitem">
        Item2
    </span>
</div>
```

And I use this CSS:

```
.mainmenu{
 height:        25px;
 padding-left:  15px;   
}
.mainmenuitem{
height:             25px;
line-height:        25px;
background-color:   #F1F2F3;
text-align:         center;
padding-top:        0px;
padding-bottom:     0px;
padding-left:       5px;
padding-right:      5px;
margin-right:       1px;
margin-left:        0px;
display:            inline-block;
vertical-align:     middle;
color:              #00537B;
}
```

But the problem is that the space between the 2 menuitems is more than 1 pixel. How to prevent this? If I use margin-right with one pixel, why is the space between more than 1 pixel? If I make it 10 pixels the space between them increases but it still does not match 10 pixels...

Comment: It is because of [`display: inline-block`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5256533/1577396).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove the white space in your code between the end of one span and the start of the next.

For example:

```
</span><span class="mainmenuitem">
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/z6FTX/)**

Comment: @Adrift - Do you need something more than newlines are counted as a space in HTML?

Comment: I just tested, the newlines are counting as space when `display:inline-block` is included.

Comment: Thanks, did not know that newlines count when using inline-block!

Answer (score 0):

`spans` are inline elements by nature, so any spaces between them are parsed as text. Removing the line break fixes it:
http://jsfiddle.net/VB8yW/

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I use `display:inline-block;`, I also add a `float:left;` to the element. This closes that gap. And then, the parent gets an `overflow:hidden;`, or some other kind of clear fix, if I need a flexible height.