# Inline-block element height issue

Tags: html, css

I have a simple example in which an outer `DIV` contains an inner `DIV` which has
`display: inline-block;`.
 Because I have set the height of the inner div, I expect the outer div to take on the same height as the inner div. Instead, the outer div is slightly taller, as you can see from the fiddle. Question: Why is this happening and how can I "fill up" the outer div without setting its height explicitly?
My goal is to have the outer div expand and shrink based on the height of the inner.

```css
.outer {
  background-color: red;
}
.inner {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 480px;
  height: 140px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: move display inline block from the inner to the outer div

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Your `.inner` div has `display: inline-block`. That means it needs an inline formatting context around it. Inline layout produces [struts](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#strut), which make room for descenders. You can see how it fits if you put a character next to the `.inner` element: http://jsfiddle.net/bs14zzeb/6/

The default `vertical-align` is to have the bottom edge of the `inline-block` box lined up with the baseline of the surrounding text. *Even if there is no surrounding text*, the layout engine still has to make room for an entire line of text.

That's why these answers are suggesting that you play with the `vertical-align` property. Setting it to `vertical-align: top`, as one answer suggests, tells the layout engine to align the top edge of the `inline-block` box with the top edge of the line box. Here, since the line height is less than 140px tall, it gets rid of the extra space on the bottom. But if the height of a line is taller than that, you'll still have extra space underneath: http://jsfiddle.net/bs14zzeb/9/

Comment: Related info and a suggestion on avoiding the extra height: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20107222/1173555

Comment: @guest Thanks for your detailed answer. A follow up question: why adding text inside the <div class="inner> will also fix the issue?

Comment: (edit) oh you're right, when you add text to the inner div, that causes the default `vertical-align: baseline` to line up the baseline from inside the box with the baseline of the text outside the box. which when it does that, I think it causes the line boxes to be arranged so that the descender doesn't stick out anymore

Comment: https://drafts.csswg.org/css2/#valdef-vertical-align-baseline see the wording here, for an empty inner div, there's no baseline, so it aligns the bottom edge with the baseline outside. for inner div with text, align that baseline with the baseline outside. usually the line boxes are sized such that they no longer stick out when lined up that way

Answer (score 17):

When using inline-block don't forget to set a [`vertical-align` property <sup>*MDN*</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align)

```css
.outer {
    background-color: red;
}
.inner {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;     /* tada!!!! */
    width: 480px;
    height: 140px;
    background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```

Alternatively, use CSS flex:

```css
.outer {
    display: flex;
    background-color: red;
}
.inner {
    width: 480px;
    height: 140px;
    background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

The default vertical alignment for inline elements is baseline, so you need to set it to top or middle:

```css
.outer {
    background-color: red;
}
.inner {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 480px;
    height: 140px;
    background-color: green;
     vertical-align:top;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

It's because your `#inner` has a display property set to `inline-block`.  To fix, change the display to `block`, or set the `vertical-align` property to `top`.

## `display: inline-block`:

```css
.outer {
  background-color: red;
}
.inner {
  width: 480px;
  height: 140px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```

## `vertical-align: 0`:

```css
.outer {
  background-color: red;
}
.inner {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 480px;
  height: 140px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the `display: inline-block;` property. Try `display: block;` instead.

http://jsfiddle.net/bs14zzeb/7/

Answer (score 1):

```
.outer {
    line-height: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`.outer{font-size:0}` will do the job

```css
.outer {
  background-color: red;
  font-size:0 
}
.inner {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 480px;
  height: 140px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```