# Is Angular adding margin/padding to my component?

Tags: html, angular, sass, padding, margin

I'm facing a little problem.. I'm trying to build some kind of "Matrix" to build a snake game in angular, and for some reason, there is a margin / padding I can not remove. Here is my code:

```html
<!-- snake.component.html -->
<div id="ng-snake-main">
  <div *ngFor="let row of matrix" class="row">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let box of row.boxes>
      <snake-box [box]="box"></snake-box>
    </ng-container>
  </div>
</div>
```

```html
<!-- box.component.html -->
<div class="box"></div>
```

Both using the same style file:

```
// styles.scss

.row {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.box {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: blue;

  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;

  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

so, why is there a space between rows??? I think that it doesn't make sense, but I'm sure I'm missing something. I'll left some screenshots:

In this screenshot you can check that the "snake-box" component is adding some kind of margin.

[image: screenshot1]

In this other screenshot you can see that the div actually doesn't have margin/padding.

[image: screenshot2]

Is angular adding margin to my component? If yes, how can I remove it?

Comment: can you provide the screen shot of your matrix

Comment: It's not because of Angular, but due to  `display: inline-block`. The answers https://stackoverflow.com/a/27536461/9471852 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/20107222/9471852 will help you understand the issue better.

Comment: Bootstrap version?

Comment: which framework would you be using for css ( angular-materials, bootstrap, primeng)?

Comment: @Siddhant, you were right. I added `vertical-align: top` and it worked like charm. Thanks for your response!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to you problem is CSS FLEX.
It would work with these styles:

```
// styles.scss

.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.box {
  background-color: blue;

  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;

  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

If you want more information about flexbox, here is an interesting link https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: Hi, I tried with flexbox and it was the same, the solution was to add a `vertical-align: top;` in the `.box` class!

Comment: Are you using bootstrap in your application ? If yes, it would be better not to use the same classes.