# Why is the height of <form> more than the height of the <textarea> inside it?

Tags: html, css, height

Minimal example for my question:

```js
console.log(document.getElementById('form').offsetHeight)
console.log(document.getElementById('textarea').offsetHeight)
```

```css
form {
  background: orange;
}

textarea {
  background: lightblue;
  border: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<form id="form"><textarea id="textarea"></textarea></form>
```

The `<textarea>` has a height of 100px but `<form>` has a height of 4px? Where is the extra 4px of height for the `<textarea>` coming from? How can I eliminate the extra height?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's because the textarea's `display` property is [initially set as `inline-block` (see the **Styling with CSS** section)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea#styling_with_css). [This stack overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27536428/inline-block-element-height-issue)'s accepted answer provides a nice explanation of why it's displaying the additional "height" (that you're experiencing). According to the post, the following solutions seem to remedy the issue:

1. set the `display` property to `block` *or*
2. set the `vertical-align` property to `top`

With `display: block`:

```css
form {
  background: orange;
  padding: 0;
}

textarea {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background: lightblue;
  height: 100px;
  display: block; 
}
```

```html
<form id="form"><textarea id="textarea"></textarea></form>
```

With `vertical-align: top`:

```css
form {
  background: orange;
  padding: 0;
}

textarea {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background: lightblue;
  height: 100px;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<form id="form"><textarea id="textarea"></textarea></form>
```

Answer (score -1):

A `<textarea>` is inherently  a `display-block` (essentially adding a 'space').

Try adding `display: block`

```css
form {
  background: orange;
  padding: 0;
}

textarea {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: block; 
  background: lightblue;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<form id="form"><textarea id="textarea"></textarea></form>
```