# Grid using calc() show extra pixels

Tags: php, css

I created a grid using the Pods plugin. For some reason, there are extra pixels at the *bottom* of each div (see the white space). I've gone through the code multiple times and cannot find a reason for this. Below is the css for the grid. Would anyone know where the white space is coming from?

link: http://test.mpluczenik.com/#work

Thank you!

Functions.php:

```
// Add Image size for Portfolio List
if ( function_exists( 'add_theme_support' ) ) { 
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
// additional image sizes
add_image_size('portfolio-thumb', 300, 300, true ); // (cropped)
}
```

Pods template:

```
<div class="portfolio-list">
<a href="{@permalink}">
    <div class="overlay">
        <a href="{@permalink}">{@post_thumbnail.portfolio-thumb}
        </a>
        <p>
        <a href="{@permalink}">{@post_title}
        </a>
        </p>
    </div>
</a>
```

CSS:

```
div .portfolio-list{
border: 0px;
padding: 0px;
width: calc(20%);
overflow: hidden;
position: relative;
display: inline-block;
float:left;

}

img.attachment-portfolio-thumb{
width:100% !important;
height:100%!important;
}

div .portfolio-list p{
display: none;
color:#000;
}

div .overlay:hover:after {
content: ' ';
position: absolute;
left: 0;
right: 0;
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
background-color: rgba(234,79,38,.75);
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
border:none;
margin:0;
padding:0;

}

div .portfolio-list:hover p {
display:block;
z-index: 9999;
position:absolute;
bottom:50px;
left:0px;
text-align: center;
width:100%;
overflow:hidden;
color:#fff;
margin: 0px;
}


div .portfolio-list:hover a{
color:#fff;
font-weight: bold;
opacity: 50%;
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: awesome! would you know by any chance as to why this works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An inline block has a line height and that is where the extra space is coming from. You can remove the line hight by adding `line-height: 0` to your css selector `div .portfolio-list`. More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20107222/1608110).