# zero size invisible input has a space

Tags: html, css, input, size, invisible

I use the following to replace hidden input since hidden input can not get focus:

```
  <input style="height:0;width:0;padding:0;border:none" type="text" />
```

The input element has a certain spaces on screen. Look at debugger, it has zero size and no margin, no padding, no borders.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 3):

This has been answered by another related question here:
[Why does inline-block cause this div to have height?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20106428/2126792)

**Long story short:**
Input elements usually default to `display: inline-block;` and inline-block input elements respect the line-height of thier parent element over their own height. You can force it to respect `height: 0;` by changing the input to `display: block;` or alternatively by giving its parent `line-height: 0;`.