# How to remove space below empty inline-block div (and why is it there anyway?)

Tags: html, css

I have the following problem: I am creating an inline-block element (.content) within a wrapper-div (.wrapper). If there is content in the .content-div, everything works just fine. But if I remove the content from the .content-div, a space gets added below the inline-block-div.

I am not sure why this happens and how to fix it correctly. Note that after manually removing all spaces and line-breaks in my code the problem persists, but setting the font-size to 0 helps.

Also, setting vertical-align: top to the .content-div helps. I am not sure why exactly.

Whats the best way of fixing it? Why does this happen?

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/cjqvcvL3/1/

```
<p>Works fine:</p>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="content">not empty</div>
</div>

<p>Not so much:</p>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="content"></div>
</div>

.wrapper {
  background-color: red;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
 /* font-size: 0; *//* this would fix it, but why? (problem persists after manually removing all spaces and breaks) */
}

.content {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 20px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: green;
  /* vertical-align: top; *//* this would fix it, but why? */
}
```

**Update**

I have put together a new fiddle. This should better illustrate my problem. How do I get rid of the green line below the textarea?

https://jsfiddle.net/cjqvcvL3/7/

```
<div class="content"><textarea>Some&#13;&#10;Content</textarea></div>

.content {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: green;
}
```

Comment: Here is an explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20107103/4334348

Answer (score 3):

This happens because you specifically give width and height to the `.content`.
Have you considered using the `:empty` pseudo selector?

```
.content:empty {
  display: none;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/cjqvcvL3/5/

Comment: The other answers are valid as well, I guess now it's just a matter of preference. I decided to go with the :empty selector because it just makes sense when you read it in your css: you see it and you immediately know what it does and why it's there. It might save you some time when you will re-read your code in the future.

Comment: Thank you. I have updated my question to better illustrate my problem. Your answer is perfectly valid to the original questions problem.

Comment: Oh ok, then I think the font-size: 0; solution should work, right?

Comment: I think I will go wit hthe font-size: 0 solution. But I am not sure why it works or why the problem happens in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/silviagreen/cjqvcvL3/3/)

To remove the gap, you have to surround the content div with a wrapper with font-size:0.
The reason is exained here: [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20107103/4334348)

> **inline-block**
>
> This value causes an element to generate an inline-level block container. The inside of an inline-block is formatted as a block box, and the element itself is formatted as an atomic inline-level box.
>
> **inline**
>
> This value causes an element to generate one or more inline boxes.
>
> The most important part for this topic would be that the element itself get's formatted not just the content. Every inline-block element will be seen as atomic inline box and thus take up space.

```
.wrapper2 {
 background-color: red;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  font-size:0;

}
```

Comment: Thank you. I have updated my question to better illustrate my problem. Your answer is perfectly valid to the original questions problem.

Answer (score -1):

Setting your the content display to block instead of inline-block fixes the problem.

```
.content {
  display: block;
  height: 20px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: green;
  /* vertical-align: top; *//* this fixes it  */
}
```

This explains why setting vertical-align to top fixes the problem as well:

> The **vertical-align** CSS property specifies the vertical alignment of an
>   inline or table-cell box.

Comment: Thank you. I have updated my question to better illustrate my problem. Your answer is perfectly valid to the original questions problem.