# CSS Animate button to appear

Tags: css, reactjs

In the React app I'm building, I would like a button to be hidden until certain conditions are met. Then I'd to animate it in from underneath another element.
At the moment I am always rendering the button and adding a class of "hidden" when I'd like it hidden.
The SASS looking something like this:

```
button {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 63px;
  transition: height 250ms ease-in-out;
  font-size: 24px;

  &.hidden {
    height: 0;
  }
}
```

But when the button hides, the element gets smaller, but the text is still visible. Similar to this: https://jsfiddle.net/dtu56e1j/

What am I doing wrong?
Or is there a better way to get a button to animate in?

Comment: Couple caveats here; `height` won't animate on IE, and it only pertains to the parent box the text sits in and not the font inside. You might consider instead [transform: scale()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/scale) but be leary of overuse of `transform`.

Comment: I had a go with `scaleY()`, but that didn't give me the desired effect either. Thanks for the IE warning.

Comment: Got a visual example of what you want?

Comment: Similar to https://davidwalsh.name/demo/css-slide.php , except the pink area would be a button. And the white area wouldn't remain, that would also disappear.

Comment: I want to hide the "Button to Hide" https://jsfiddle.net/dtu56e1j/

Comment: On your fiddle example just change `height: 0` to `display: none` if you want it removed; or  use the `visibility` property to toggle visible/hidden in the same manner if you just want it to "hide"

Comment: But would that animate nicely?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMO the other answers provide working, but complicated solutions to your problem. Simply put, you're missing a single CSS property - `overflow: hidden`.

I created this [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-gsfwqh) to illustrate the point.

However, the only modification necessary to the original code is this:

```
button {
  overflow: hidden;
  [...]
}
```

---

Fiddle to better match use-case: https://jsfiddle.net/smn6xgv2/

Because the button element has some internal padding, setting `height: 0` doesn't completely remove the element from the display. To address that issue, we wrap the `button` inside a `div` and then animate the height of the `div`.

Additionally, the `div` should be left with the default `display: block`. In the original example, the `display: inline-block` causes the browser to reserve a minimum height of `line-height`. More info in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20106428/why-does-inline-block-cause-this-div-to-have-height/20107222)

Comment: ^ yaaaa, this guy understood what was being asked better than I haha. +1

Comment: I think the effect I'm trying to achieve is this: https://js-mksshk.stackblitz.io . Which you can see doesn't work in the same way.

Comment: @Votemike how much control do you have over the HTML? IE could you wrap the button inside a div?

Comment: I could do that. I think I tried, but it still didn't work.

Comment: @Votemike It seems to work "ok" https://jsfiddle.net/4zs9wjo6/1/. It looks to still reserve space because it is `display: inline-block`. Is that necessary for your situation?

Comment: No, I don't think `display: inline-block` is needed in my example

Comment: So was it just the width that was missing?

Answer (score 0):

With a little work you could use `translateY` to get this done nicely

```js
const el = document.querySelector("#testButton");

setInterval(() => {
  el.classList.toggle("hidden");
}, 2000);
```

```css
button {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: darkblue;
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
  height: 63px;
  transition: transform 250ms ease-in-out;
  font-size: 24px;
}

button.hidden {
  transform: translateY(63px); /* or -63px to invert */
}

/* Make a wrapper class so that your button disappears on transform */
.wrapper {
  height: 63px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <button id="testButton">My Button!</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Sneaky. I'll see if I can get this to work if I can't find an actual hiding solution.

Comment: I think this will be the most performant way you can achieve this effect with just CSS alone, though you could also look into using something like `react-transition-group` and conditional rendering https://github.com/reactjs/react-transition-group/tree/v1-stable best of luck I hope you find something that suits your needs

Comment: I was looking at `react-transition-group` but it seems a lot to do for a simple animation