# Line height behaving differently inside container

Tags: html, css

I've run into an interesting problem with `line-height`.

```css
.text {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 11px;
  line-height: 12px;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="text-container"><span class="text">Hello</span></div>
  <span class="text">Hello</span>
</div>
```

In [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vhgf9ps7/) *above* there are 2 spans, both with `font-size` and `line-height` set, inside a flex container. One of the spans is inside a `div` and the other one isn't.

The spans themselves have a height of `12px`, but the div has a height of `18px`, causing the two spans to be out of line. If I add `line-height: 0;` to the div, then the problem is fixed and the div is `12px` tall.

The spans must be on the same line, and one of them must be inside a container. `display: block` works, but for my purposes this element needs to be inline for certain use cases.

What's causing the div to have this extra height, and is there a nicer solution than having to set `line-height: 0;` on the div?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20106428/why-does-inline-block-cause-this-div-to-have-height/20107222#20107222). It's to do with how `line-height` is calculated for `inline` elements. I've fixed it by setting `font-size: 0;` on the div containing the span.

Answer (score 0):

The display on the span elements are different. The one inside the div has a display: inline, while the span standalone is display block. If you would like them to react the same, simply put a display on the element.

Comment: The one inside the div can't be a block element for my purposes.

Answer (score 0):

If you set `line-height: 12px;` on the container it kind of works. But if you look closely there is still a small space.

```css
.text {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 11px;
  line-height: 12px;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  
  line-height: 12px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="text-container">
      <span class="text">Hello</span>
    </div>
    
    <span class="text">Hello</span>
  </div>
</body>
```