# Force floated elements to start in a new line

Tags: css, css-float

I have a list with floated `<li>` elements, the heights are different, thats the problem. I know I know theres an alternative, `display:inline-block` but this propery adds extra spaces, and I dont know why.

My css:

```
ul {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    list-style:none;
    width:700px;
}

ul li {
    float:left;
    border:1px solid #000;
    width:24%;
    margin:0 0.3% 20px 0.3%;
    font-size:11px;
}

.yellow {
    background:yellow;
}
```

online preview: http://jsfiddle.net/f3CA3/1/

Comment: Not possible with CSS only. Except the `display: table-*` family maybe. `inline-block` does what it says: do not ignore whitespace (inline) but act as block (expand horizontally as much as possible).

Comment: For `inline-block` and whitespace see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5256533/a-space-between-inline-block-list-items

Comment: Something like this -> http://jsfiddle.net/f3CA3/3/ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it clearing the sides as:

```
clear:both;
```

or maybe

```
clear:right;
```

just as an example, could be also;

```
clear:left;
```

Comment: Why would you `clear:right` when there's nothing being floated to the right to be cleared?