# css two boxes could not divide 100% of the parent width

Tags: css

Here is the JS fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nettrinity/8YXsQ/

```
<div class="outer-box">
    <div class="inner-one">30%</div>
    <div class="inner-two">70%</div>
</div>
```

I want them to divide 100%, but there is alway a gap between. What is it? since I set all margin, padding, and border to 0. Is it a bug?

Thank you!

Comment: yes, how can I delete the gap?

Answer (score 3):

You have set the `div` elements to be `inline-block`, which causes them to act like simple text. What you see between them is a simple space. If you remove the linebreak from in between them, and set the second `div`'s width to `70%`, you will get the correct results.

http://jsfiddle.net/8YXsQ/9/

```
<div class="outer-box">
    <div class="inner-one"></div><div class="inner-two"></div>
</div>
```

Anyway, there are a few alternatives to `inline` and `inline-block` to place elements next to each other. Try using `float:left`, or `display:table` for the parent and `display:table-cell` for the child elements and see what best fits your needs.

Comment: There are many reasons to use `inline-block` over `float` and one should not be preferred over the other. They both have their own issues...use of one or the other will depend entirely on the effect trying to be achieved.

Comment: Thanks for this tip. It reminds me another painful puzzle about gap between li element.

Comment: @Paulie_D You are perfectly right, good point. I will modify my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

please try: float:left;
(I'am updated my jsfiddle link!)

http://jsfiddle.net/8YXsQ/8/

CSS:

```
    .outer-box {
    width:200px;
    background-color: #ccc;
    height:30px;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    border:0;
}
.inner-one {
    width:30%;
    background-color: yellow;
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    border:0;
    display:inline-block;
    float:left;
}
.inner-two {
    width:70%;
    background-color: green;
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    border:0;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Comment: If you update the link, other people may not see the problem.

Answer (score 0):

you can erase the gap setting font-size to 0 and back to a normal.
http://jsfiddle.net/8YXsQ/3/

```
.outer-box {
    width:200px;
    background-color: #ccc;
    height:30px;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    border:0;
    font-size:0;
}
.inner-one {
    width:30%;
    background-color: yellow;
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    border:0;
    display:inline-block;
    font-size:14px;
}
.inner-two {
    width:70%;
    background-color: green;
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    border:0;
    display:inline-block;
    font-size:14px;
}
```

or remove the space in your html

```
<div class="outer-box">
    <div class="inner-one"></div><!--
    --><div class="inner-two"></div>
</div>
```

or

```
<div class="outer-box">
    <div class="inner-one"></div><div class="inner-two"></div>
</div>
```

You could use `display:table;` too http://jsfiddle.net/8YXsQ/11/

```
.outer-box {
    width:200px;
    display:table;
    border-collapse:collapse;
}
.inner-one, .inner-two {
    display:table-cell;
    background:green;
}
.inner-one {
    width:30%;
    background:yellow;
    height:1.2em; /* in case tested with no content */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Removing the newline between `divs` did the trick :

```
<div class="outer-box">
    <div class="inner-one"></div><div class="inner-two"></div>
</div>
```

See [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8YXsQ/10/)

Another alternative would be to remove the font-size :

```
.outer-box {
    font-size:0;
}
```

Or just use `float:left` instead of `display:inline-block`...

Answer (score 0):

I am answering my own question. 
This problem is closely related to this one:

[A Space between Inline-Block List Items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5256533/a-space-between-inline-block-list-items/11906591#11906591)

In short, as skreborn said,
inline and inline block elements will not be 0 gap, even if you set the border, margin and padding to 0.

Maybe it is not suppose to be. The way to fix it is to set the parent font-size to 0. (re-set the width, font-size or height for children elements if they cllapse)