# Weird margins after sortable in jqueryUi

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable, jquery-ui-draggable

I have this weird problem with margins in sortable after dragging.
margins seem to disappear and boxed stick to each other.
Played around with it for quite a bit and couldn't find the problem.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/YsG6S/
And the CSS:

```
ul { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; margin-bottom: 10px; width:500px; }
li { width: 200px; height:100px; display:inline-block; border:1px solid black; }
```

(Sort and drag to see the margin issue)

Comment: do you want the white space to be there between the left/right `li`s like it is now? or should they all be collapsed?

Comment: Specify the margin in your CSS. It will solve the problem. but I'm not sure what causes it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [A Space between Inline-Block List Items](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5256533/a-space-between-inline-block-list-items)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the `li` elements to `display: block` and float them.

```
/* changes */
li { 
    display: block;
    margin-right: 2px; /*if you want the space*/
    float: left;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mKeAL/

**EDIT 1**
Looks like this is a whitespace/display-inline bug of some sort with jquery UI.

General bugginess reported here: http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/6942

Author replied 'works for me', pointing at this working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/T8gkC/ but note the whitespace on the list items in the HTML. I remember an IE5.5 (6) bug that had a similar resolution. If you make the HTML "normal", the bug is back: http://jsfiddle.net/94Vs2/ Adding margin to the list items helps a tiny bit but if you look closely, the bug is still there.

So... if you *need* them to be `display: inline-block` you might try removing the white space in between each `<li>`.

**EDIT 2**
According to the answer at [A Space between Inline-Block List Items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5256533/a-space-between-inline-block-list-items) you can also set a `font-size` of 0 on the `ul` and reset it on the `li`: http://jsfiddle.net/YsG6S/2/ Works fine, margin wise. That said, note the difference in drag/drop/sort interactions with the `block/float` method vs any of the `inline-block` methods.

**EDIT 3**
Another option is to drink mightily from the HTML5 fountain and *omit your closing* `</li>` *tags*.  http://jsfiddle.net/mKeAL/1/

Comment: Why did we had such problem?