# how to make divs inline-block?

Tags: html, css

I have following html

```
<div class="main-conteiner">
    <div class="block">First</div>
    <div class="block">Second</div>
</div>
```

---

And this css

```
.main-conteiner {
  width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.block {
  width: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  background: red;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box; 
}

div {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

---

I need to arrange both `div`s in a same line. But instead of that it brakes down into two lines.
I cant figure out where I've done a mistake.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/QWg92/)

Comment: possible duplicate of [A Space between Inline-Block List Items](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5256533/a-space-between-inline-block-list-items)

Comment: It's due to the whitespace in the HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**Here is a nice explanation and various other ways to to get rid of it**](http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/)

Some of them are as others,

```
<div class="main-conteiner">
    <div class="block">this is just a div</div><!-- 
    --><div class="block">this is another div</div>
</div>
```

or

```
<div class="main-conteiner">
    <div class="block">
    this is just a div</div><div class="block">this is another div</div>
</div>
```

or

```
<div class="main-conteiner">
    <div class="block">this is just a div</div
    ><div class="block">this is another div</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/QWg92/4/)

Its because `inline-block` takes into account white space in your HTML, simply remove the line break between the two elements.

Revised HTML

```
    <div class="main-conteiner">
        <div class="block">this is just a div</div><div class="block">this is another div</div>
    </div>
```

The reason being that inline elements are taken into account effectively in the same way as text, a new line/line break separation will always be rendered as a white space- which in addition to 2*50% will bring the width to greater than 100%.

---

### [Alternative Solution](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/QWg92/8/)

To stop the linebreak in your HTML being rendered as an additional space, simply set `font-size` on the container to 0, then set font-size for the child `div`, this will mean the rendered space has a size of zero, thus no width, so will not compromise the width calculations.

```
.main-conteiner {
    width: 600px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    font-size:0;
}
.block {
    width: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
    background: red;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    font-size:15px;
}
div {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use display:inline-block, you should know and remenber that any space in HTML in between tags will be rendered as white-space. like in between two words.

One easy way to avoid yhis is to bring together closing and opening brackets of tags. **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/QWg92/2/)**

```
<div class="main-conteiner">
        <div class="block">this is just a div</div><div class="block">this is another div</div>
    </div>
```

or insert a comment in between

```
<div class="main-conteiner">
        <div class="block">this is just a div</div><!--
         --><div class="block">this is another div</div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this CSS :

```
.block {
  width: 50%;
  display: block;
  background: red;
  float:left;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: i need to learn how to use inline-block to achive this. Thanks for the answer :)

Comment: Ok, so just use float:left; you can keep your display: inline-block

Answer (score 0):

If you want both the `div`s which have a class of `.block` to be on same line then just use a `float`

```
.block {
  float:left;
  width: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  background: red;  
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

define your **parent** `font-size:0;` and **child define** `font-size:12px` as **like your design**

**as like this**

```
.main-conteiner{font-size:0;}
.block{font-size:12px;}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/QWg92/3/)**

### -------------------

**2nd option is this**

now write your html code as like this

```
<div class="main-conteiner">
  <div class="block">this is just a div</div><!--   --><div class="block">this is another div</div>
</div>
```

**[Demo 2](http://jsfiddle.net/QWg92/6/)**

Answer (score 0):

You have to change a line in `.block` class

```
.block {
  width: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  background: red;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box; 
}
```

You can have a look here: [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/6Tfxt/)

Answer (score 0):

```
.main-conteiner {
  width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.block {
  width: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  background: red;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box; 
  float:left;
}

div {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<div class="main-conteiner">
        <div class="block">this is just a div</div><!--
        --><div class="block">this is another div</div>
</div>
```

comment is for removing the spaces between the DIVs.

Comment: Thanq for checking it once again. Now it works fine @Vereos :)

Comment: This is a completely different answer that doesn't add nothing new, since this solution was already pointed out by several answers; Plus, you didn't even edit the first line of your original answer, which still says you have to reduce width to 49%. Still -1 :(