# Box model width discrepancy between inline-block container and content

Tags: css

I'm trying to lay out my page precisely by specifying CSS attribute values in **pixels**. However, in one instance where I'm trying to limit the maximum number of tiles per row in a tiled display, I'm finding that my calculations are off by a puzzling, unknown (to me) factor.

The following two fiddles illustrate my question:

- [Good fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3f7rm44L/2/): A max of two tiles are displayed per row in the left column. But **I don't understand** why the `max-width` attribute of my container has to be greater than the sum of `margin + border + padding + width` for the content tiles.
- [Bad fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3f7rm44L/1/): I'm not getting the 2-tiles-per-row output I want, despite specifying what I believe to be precisely calculated box model attributes for the content and container elements.

What am I missing in my calculations? Why is `margin + border + padding + width` for the inner tiles not adding up exactly to my `max-width` for the container?

Answer (score 0):

It is a natural thing in HTML, that it puts some space between the elements as it does with words. You can change your html code (the part with 'col-1-tile') so it looks like this:

```
<div class="inline-block col-1-tile">A</div><div class="inline-block col-1-tile">B</div><div class="inline-block col-1-tile">C</div>
```

Or you can try to change `font-size` of those elements to `0px`. Both will do the trick.
More on that topic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5256533/a-space-between-inline-block-list-items) or [here](http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/)

Comment: EDIT: it doesn't put the space everywhere, but obviously 'inline-block' is one of those elements, where it does. It is known under term "whitespace dependent method".