# Why are my pipes fuzzy?

Tags: html, css, pipe

I am creating a sitemap, and for some reason on all browsers the different separation pipes have different fuzziness.

Chrome:

[image]

```css
.header a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.header li {
  display: inline-block;
}
.header li:after {
  content: "|";
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="http://test.com">Mainpage</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://example.com">Handbook</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://amazon.com">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://place.com">Donate</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://obama.com">Forum</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Can somebody please help me fix this? It makes so sense.

Comment: Do you want something like this http://jsfiddle.net/juz1o2cf/3/

Comment: Font antialiasing (technically, sub-pixel rendering). Incidentally, Windows uses a different algorithm for that so the pipes should appear sharp on Windows. Some browsers support [disabling font smoothing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-smooth) but not all do, and it’s nonstandard.

Comment: Then why are some aliased and some not? Why isn't it all or none?

Comment: @pshahab48 All of them are, it just so happens that some of the characters happen to fall bang onto the pixel, while others fall between the pixels and need to be smoothed.

Comment: This is simple anti-aliasing as mentioned by Konrad, it makes perfect sense. Hope @KonradRudolph writes an answer for you to accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome and Firefox use different techniques for rendering fonts. That's why they look different (more or less smooth and fuzzy) in each browser. It is then also different on the several operating systems.

If you need it to look consistent every time, you should probably use an image or the CSS `border` attribute and similar. Another option is CSS [`text-rendering`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-rendering).

Answer (score 1):

Semantically speaking the pipe `|` is not the way to go, because it has a different meaning than what you're trying to accomplish (in Unix terms: pipe'ing two commands together, but also has functions in Mathematical terms etc).

You're (mis)using it as a divider, which is a visual (style) element. chrki's solution to use a border would be best:

```css
.header a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.header li {
  display: inline-block;
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  margin-left: 5px;
  padding-left: 5px;
}
.header li:first-child {
  border-left: 0;
  margin-left: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="http://test.com">Mainpage</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://example.com">Handbook</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://amazon.com">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://place.com">Donate</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://obama.com">Forum</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

ps: and I've thrown in a "first-child" to only let the divider appear between elements

ps2: the "Space between inline-block"-problem appears in this solution, an answer to that can be found here: [A Space between Inline-Block List Items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5256533/a-space-between-inline-block-list-items)