# Making closing and opening div tags appear on same line with HAML

Tags: html, css, haml, whitespace, margin

I found out recently that HTML does a weird thing with whitespace where `div` tags that open and close on different lines each have a margin of about `4px` between them.

You can fix this by putting the closing `div` tag and the trailing opening `div` tag on the same line, but otherwise the best way to rectify this seems to be over-riding it by giving them absolute positioning and a negative margin.

Can I accomplish the former with HAML? Preferably not the whole `div` tag and everything within it, just the ending and opening tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only option that I know (I mean is on their doc) that gives you some control of the output format is the switcher -t which can be `ugly` or the default *intended*. `ugly` will omit indentation so I guess no luck there.

Meaning for this this haml example:

```
.container
  .wrapper
    .something-esle
      a neat text here
    .something-esle
      a neat text here
```

will render with the command `haml -t ugly test.haml test.html`
 into:

```
<div class='container'>
<div class='wrapper'>
<div class='something-esle'>
a neat text here
</div>
<div class='something-esle'>
a neat text here
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

where `haml test.haml test.html` puts out :

```
<div class='container'>
  <div class='wrapper'>
    <div class='something-esle'>
      a neat text here
    </div>
    <div class='something-esle'>
      a neat text here
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

**What are you experiencing**, is a well known problem with the `display:inline` or `display:inline-block` style, where is normal to have that space since the element is treated like a char. There are a lot of hacks for it like set the font size to 0px on the container and restore it on the block or use `float` instead.

Follow these stacks for more details on the subject:

[How to remove the space between inline-block elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078239/how-to-remove-the-space-between-inline-block-elements)

[A Space between Inline-Block List Items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5256533/a-space-between-inline-block-list-items)

Comment: Floating the divs worked, that seems least dumb way to rectify it.

Comment: Please note that float have it's sins too :) look for "clearfix float", here is a good paper https://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/