# Eliminate margin when commenting

Tags: html, css

I am getting unwanted margin horizontally on my li a elements when I put a comment next to the code in the .html file. When I remove it, the margin goes away. What is going on, and is there a way I can add comments without affecting the display? Here is the code, where the comment is in the li rule:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

 <html lang="en">

 <head> 
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <meta name=”viewport” content=”width=device-width”>   
   <title>Test Navigation</title>

   <style>

ul {                   
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0; 
    background-color: white;
    position: absolute;
}

li {    
    display: inline-block;    <!--allows you to display like an inline but you can add width and height-->  
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid red;

}

li a {
  display: block;
  font-size: 1.3rem;
  text-align: center; 
  min-width:140px;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;  
  border: 1px solid black;

}   
   </style>
 </head>

 <body>


            <ul>
              <li><a class="active" href="#" >HOME</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">VIDEOS</a></li>           
              <li><a href="#">DOCUMENTS</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">SCTE</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">TRAINING</a></li>           
              <li><a href="#">EVENTS</a></li>            
            </ul>



 </body>

 </html>
```

Comment: css comment syntax is `/* COMMENT */`

Comment: Add this to your `ul`: `font-size:0;` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5256533/a-space-between-inline-block-list-items

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A Space between Inline-Block List Items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5256533/a-space-between-inline-block-list-items)

Comment: Please explain why to add ul:font-size: 0;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That part of the code is CSS and here the comments must be enclosed between `/*  */`, not `<!-- -->`. Currently that line is being ignored by the browser.

e.g.

```
display: inline-block; /* allows you to display like an inline but you can add width and height */
```

Answer (score 1):

you are in css (style tags)  so style and script is `/* */` html (other html codes) is `<!— —>` for css on your file use `/*` and `*/`

hope it helped!

```
display: inline-block; /* allows you to display like an inline but you can add width and height */
```

Comment: "_you are in css html is for css_" What?