# How to create a rails checkbox form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations

Im trying to create a checkbox table of about 20 "interests" that lets the user select as many as they want. I have a Interest & User model with a HABTM relationship (through a "interests_users"join table).

So:

1. How do i seed the interests table (just has a name:string attribute) with the names of 20 or so pre set interests?
2. How do i display these in a ERB form allowing the user to select as many as they like?

Note.. Im using the Wicked gem to create a multistep form (<-working great)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<% for interest in Interest.find(:all) %>
  <%= check_box_tag "user[interest_ids][]", interest.id, @user.interests.include?(interest) %>
  <%= interest.name %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I have all of the interests stored in an array.. how would i seed the array so i dont have to do "Interest.create :name => 'World Domination'" 20 times over ...would the following work? Interest.create :name => ["Adevnture sports", "Arts and crafts"......]

Comment: Array.each do |interest_name|
        Interest.create(:name => interest_name)
    end

Answer (score 2):

1. If you're on Rails >= 3.0, then have a look the db/seeds.rb file.  You get to put arbitrary Ruby code in that file, which you run through the Rake task `rake db:seed`.  You can just put a lot of lines like `Interest.create :name => 'World Domination'`.
2. This one is going to depend on how you set up your form.  Going off the information you've given, I'd do something like this:

   ```
   <%= form_for @user do |f| -%>
     <% Interest.all.each do |i| -%>
       <div><%= i.name -%> <%= check_box_tag 'user[interests][]', i.id, @user.interests.detect{|ui| ui.name == i.name} -%></div>
     <% end -%>
   <% end -%>
   ```

In your controller you would then be able to just update your user model's attributes.  Be sure to make sure you are able to mass-assign your parameters, and also keep in mind a limitation of the HTML spec with regard to unchecked checkboxes (read the part titled, "[Gotcha](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-check_box)").

EDIT: fixed some grammar-related typos.

Comment: I have all of the interests stored in an array.. how would i seed the array so i dont have to do "Interest.create :name => 'World Domination'" 20 times over  ...would the following work?


Interest.create :name => ["Adevnture sports", "Arts and crafts"......]

Comment: `['Adventure sports', 'Arts and crafts'].each{|i| Interest.create :name => i}`

Comment: What does the `-` do in the closing `-%>` erb insertions?

Comment: @SagarPandya It controls whitespace in the generated output.  Here's a SO answer with more details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4407862/minus-sign-at-the-end-of-a-erb-sequence