# What is the difference between "-%>" and "%>" in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, syntax

What is the difference between :

```
<% @posts.each do |p| -%>
<%= p.title %>
<% end -%>
```

and

```
<% @posts.each do |p| %>
<%= p.title %>
<% end %>
```

and is there any ?

Comment: Looks like no. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4407862/minus-sign-at-the-end-of-a-erb-sequence

Comment: @atw13 Even in Rails3, `-%>` still removes trailing newlines.

Comment: I don't know, all the pros use HAML ;)

Comment: Agreed. HAML is highly flexible.

Answer (score 2):

`-%>` means that do not insert '\n' and whitespaces after the command.

Answer (score -1):

There is no difference.

"-%>" is completely useless in Rails 3.

Comment: you should provide a link to support that.

Comment: [ASCIIcasts seems to support this notion.](http://asciicasts.com/episodes/208-erb-blocks-in-rails-3) As does [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4407909/2540204).